# OS X iconutil reports "Invalid iconset"

Tags: macos, icons, packaging

I'm packaging an existing Java Swing application as an OS X app, using JarBundler, and everything's going nicely except for adding the icon. I created PNG files in Photoshop named as follows:

```
icon_16x16.png
icon_32x32.png
icon_128x128.png
```

These went into a folder called JHOVEicons, then I ran:

```
iconutil -c icns -o JHOVEicons.icns JHOVEicons/
```

This results in the error message:

```
JHOVEicons/:error: Invalid Iconset.
```

I double-checked that the files are the size they claim to be. I tried adding 256 and 512 sizes, though supposedly a complete set isn't required. It keeps giving the same error.

What might I be doing wrong? I'm running on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 42):

I figured it out. The directory of icons which I'm converting has to have the .iconset extension.